# C/C++ Wrapper for SIMULINK models

Tags: c++, matlab, user-interface, wrapper, simulink

I have a very big C/C++ software project in Visual Studio and Eclipse. There are some third party software in the form of SIMULINK models. Is it currently possible to:

1) Write C/C++ wrapper functions for SIMULINK models?
2) Invoke the functions from external environment such as VS or Eclipse C/C++ projects to perform integration and further tasks?

I know that you can use MEX (MATLAB Exec.) functions which are C/C++ or FORTRAN wrapped for MATLAB usage. But this is not ideal for me.

**USE CASE**

My use case is based on modelling and simulation, but my subsystems are quite diverse in terms of data format. 50% is in C/C++, 35% is in SIMULINK models, and the rest are in binary executables, object code, symbol data, etc. I am doing some complex system modelling; Sorry, but cannot tell you further due to protective reasons.

From the answers I am getting, it seems people are keen to just use what Mathworks offers. My intention was to get more like a yes no answer, but so far I got good explanations too.

**UPDATE**

I will have to evaluate SIMULINK's embedded coder and see how much extra effort is required on polishing the generated code. I read that there is production-level code generation facility in Embedded Coder; should be interesting.

Comment: It appears that you don't want to use any of the mainstream methods to access simulink generated code.  What is it you wish to do?

Comment: @macduff        Just because there is a code generator doesn't mean that I have to use it. i was trying to find out if it is possible to use C/C++ wrapper to invoke SIMULINK models. And what I am trying to do is create a complex system where the subsystem designs are either in SIMULINK models, C/C++ source code, executable application, object files, binary data, etc. If you want specific details, sorry I cannot disclose due to confidentiality.

Comment: You could invoke Matlab and do a co-simulation using TCP/IP or some other IPC to communicate with the model during co-sim.  However, If the c-code generated is not efficient enough, this approach may be lacking as well.

Comment: @macduff        I am glad that you understood! I am pretty certain that MATLAB's code generator is not good enough. SIMULINK's one - I am not sure, in the process of trying at the moment. I am keen to try what you are saying about TCP comms. So, should I "fake" remote execution of my .m scripts then?

Comment: While this is possible, it will require a reasonable amount of effort.  If at all possible, use the code generated by Simulink.

Comment: @macduff        Sure, I am in the process of evaluating the embedded coder! Thanks for all the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

There are two choices depending on exactly what your requirements are:

- convert the Simulink models to C using Simulink Coder.  This effectively gets you out of the Simulink environment, so integrating the model functionality into you existing environment is identical to incorporating any other C code.  Of course you need access to Simulink Coder to do this.
- Calling the [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html).  Note you cannot call just Simulink.  You call MATLAB and issue various MATLAB commands to load, execute, and interrogate the Simulink model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew about SIMULINK coder (ex RT Workshop). Apologies that I didn't mention it in my question. The problem is that the generated code isn't very efficient and not well-structured. For a large+complex system e.g. level 4 turbine engine, the generate code for 12 -13 SIMULINK models would be a nightmare to fix.  There is also another risk that if you have any changes in the model (the customer changes), the generated code needs regenerating and also other things. We also have to be careful about vendor IPRs with those 3rd party models.

Comment: @hagubear The idea behind Simulink Coder is not to edit the generated code for the reasons you mentioned. The model becomes the golden reference, not the code. If the code is not efficient enough, you problably need to optimise it and customise it with Embedded Coder, which is designed to generate production code (as opposed to prototyping code).

Comment: If you're talking about incorporating calls to a dozen or more separate models there's no chance that you want to use the MATLAB API approach.  You need to have a process in place where any changes to the models are flagged and the code regenerated (using Embedded Coder as am304 mentions).  Also, I'm not sure where IPR comes into it -- it's far easier to protect a compiled model than a Simulink .slx model.

Comment: @PhilGoddard    Just because there is a SIMULINK code generator doesn't necessarily mean that it's the only way, at least that's what I think. It seems SIMULINK only offers S-function (for calling legacy C/C++ code inside a model) and Embedded Coder. I was interested to know if the converse is possible because LabVIEW offers this facility. Also, I currently have MATLAB/SIMULINK license but it costs ridiculous amount of money to maintain all toolboxes/blocksets. And also, my product requirements are growing signficantly and pointing towards extra blocksets to be purchased from Mathworks :(

Comment: Your original question is clear in that you want an external app (written in C++) to call into Simulink.  But similarly, my answer (I think is clear) in saying that yes that is possible.  It can be achieved using calls to the MATLAB API (from C code) given in the link in the answer.  I don't believe that's the right approach, and the more complex your system, the more I believe that the code generation approach is the right one.

Comment: @PhilGoddard     Annoyingly yes, I am coming to a point where this seems like an option out of many that I have currently on my mind. I will be attending a seminar on SIMULINK next Tuesday about control system, hopefully it will give me a nudge!